# How can I find references to an external class without source code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search

Is there a straightforward way to find references in my code to a class in an external library (jar without source) if I don't already have a file open that has a reference to the class?

For instance, say I want to find all references in my code to `System.out.println()` but I don't already have code open that uses `println`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open any type (class or interface) via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on a Mac). When the class/interface source opens, select a method or field (instance variable) in that class, right-click, and choose *References*.

If you don't have the source code, you'll see the Class File Editor, "Source not found" window.  If you don't already have the "link with editor" icon enabled, either enable it or select the *Navigate* menu, *Show In*, *Package Explorer*.  Then in the package explorer, select a method or field (instance variable) in that class, right-click, and choose *References*.

Comment: This is correct, but still to complicated. If the class file editor comes up, just select your method/field/constructor in the outline view, hit Ctrl-Shift-G (or use the appropriate context menu). The outline provides _many_ features for class files, including setting break points and similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to perform the following (not exactly straightforward) sequence:

1. Open and edit an existing class by adding a reference to, say, `System.out.println()`
2. Organize imports (`ctrl-shift-o`)
3. Place the cursor on `println` and type `ctrl-shift-g` or search, references, workspace.
4. Close the class without saving it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to do this using a [`File Search`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-45.htm). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and put in `System.out.println`. Adjust the scope of the search according to your needs (I usually set it to `Enclosing Project` or `Selected Resource`).